# HTTPS issue with ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a webservice using ajax call(javascript) to return json.It is working fine.But when i changed my site to HTTPS it is not working.What will be the reason?

```
function GetReportguid1, callback) { 
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/demo/Datapage.aspx/GetData",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify({
           guiddemo: guid1           
       }),
       success: function (results) {          
           callback(results);
       },
       error: AjaxFailed
   });


};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237076/ajax-https-request-issue

Answer (score 0):

Add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the server

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: `https://www.yoursite.com`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

And try use JSONP instead.

Comment: JS not loading in HTTS